# Does exist a Microcontroller Kit for ESP microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller-kit

I really like the microcontroller suite provided by mathematica but it seems to be limited to atmel microcontrollers.

Does exist a way to have the same capabilities using an ESP based controller like the ESP32?

If not, how "hard" would it be to try to adapt the existing software to make it work with an ESP board?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the ESP and other 32bit controllers are not as of yet officially supported in `Microcontrollerkit`. But there are [many Arduino 32bits](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/mctoolkit/gallery/index.html) that are.

```
Needs["MicrocontrollerKit`"]
EntityList["MicrocontrollerVendor"]
```

They recently added support for these boards, so with luck we will maybe see some ESPs or other brands. However, for now, assuming you're programming your ESP with the Wiring language and the arduino IDE, there is a work around that I use to program my ESP32 with mathematica.

Here is an example to generate the code within a notebook you can copy and paste:

```
code = 
 MicrocontrollerEmbedCode[
  ssmd, <|"Target" -> "ArduinoUno", "Inputs" -> {"A0" -> "Analog", "A1" -> "Analog", "A2" -> "Analog"},"Outputs" -> {"Serial"}|>, <|"ConnectionPort" -> None|>, <|"Language" -> "Wiring"|>]Framed[StringTrim[code["SourceCode"]], Background -> Darker[Black, 0.4]]
```

Or from Suba Thomas from Wolfram, who [wrote this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1821155?p_p_auth=ley8VxQ8):

```
dir = CreateDirectory[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Demo"}]]; 
MicrocontrollerEmbedCode[
  NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{Which[x > 0, 0, True, 1]}, {x}}, {x}, {}, {Automatic}, Automatic, SamplingPeriod -> 2], 
  <|"Target" -> "ArduinoUno", "Outputs" -> 13 -> "Digital"|>, 
  <|"ConnectionPort" -> "p"|>, 
  <|"Language" -> "Wiring", "WorkingDirectory" -> dir, "CleanIntermediate" -> False, "CreateBinary" -> False|>]; 

SystemOpen[RenameFile[FileNameJoin[{dir, "Demo.cpp"}], FileNameJoin[{dir, "Demo.ino"}]]]
```

Which will generate code and put it in a new window in the arduino IDE...though you can't run it over and over again, you'll have to modify the code some for that.

Good luck! I used this method to program and control a [fly wheel inverted pendulum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lzw3ZGTuMUU) with an esp32 and mathematica. It was a fun project :)

Comment: Is the code for your inverted pendulum available somewhere? It's really cool!

Comment: @CarlLange there is https://github.com/drthegirlfriend/Reaction-Wheel-Inverted-Pendulum !

Comment: Thanks a lot and cool work!

Comment: Thank you very much, i see that the generated code needs something from the avr/interrupt library, how are you getting around that?

Comment: @zurg my generated code has nothing to do with any libraries? Perhaps post the error...also don’t forget to check and mark as correct if this answers your question :)